# Non-invasive javascript performance agent?

Tags: javascript, performance, http, metrics, agent

I am seeking to (legitimately) plant bugging in my web pages to collect and report information about website performance.

Preference for internally hosted. While I expect that there are commercial offerings out there (e.g. Google Analytics) I'm keen to find something we can run entirely in-house (its not a public website and may contain sensitive data).

Also, I'm looking for something where it can report back to an independent URL - i.e. not relying on adding in a reverse-proxy / recording results within existing webserver logs. Indeed, I'd prefer something which does not require access to the webserver logs logs at all (other than those for the URL the bug reports back to).

I need to be able to monitor bulk traffic - so things tools like pagespeed and tamperdata are not appropriate.

I've tried googling but just seem to be getting lots of noise about the performance of javascript and web pages rather than how to actually measure these.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks chiborg. I'd kind of forgotten about this it was so long ago I asked. Yes, I was aware of PiWik - but not been very impressed with either its implementation nor the quality of documentation.

I'm currently working on a solution using [Boomerang](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/06/performance_testing_with_boomerang/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the open source analytics software [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) and write a plugin for it that sends the performance data to it.